# Interactive cd (directory browser)

Tags: utilities

Sometimes when working in deeply nested file hierarchies (e.g. Java code) I find it annoying to traverse from one leaf to another. My usual cd-up looks like:

```
$ cd ../../..
# Oops, not enough
$ cd ..
# one more
$ cd ..
```

If I want to edit a file I can `vim dir` and interactively open desired file.
Is there some utility that allows to interactively change directory? Explorers/commanders (`mc`, `vifm`) are too heavy for such a task.

I have searched the internet, but my keywords seem to return nothing of relevance.

Added to clarify:

I am searching for an utility (let's call it `vcd`) that presents me an interactive directory tree which I can traverse and select where to cd.
From user perspective `vim .` calls hypothetical `vcd` which in the end executes `vim $filename`. I would like similar functionality (directory browser), just in the end to end up with `CWD` changed to interactively selected directory. I hope this makes my intentions more clear.

Comment: You mean - press a key and `cd ..; ls` is executed like how you use `-` command in vim directory browsing?

Comment: with [`edbrowse`](http://edbrowse.sourceforge.net) you can do this w/ dirs, google.com, email, files, databases... maybe other stuff?

Comment: Take a look at [deer](https://github.com/Vifon/deer) and/or [blscd](https://github.com/D630/blscd). They use Miller columns and are meant to provide navigation, one for bash and one for zsh.

Answer (score 3):

Try [fzf-fs](https://github.com/D630/fzf-fs).

Install [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#installation):

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.git ~/.fzf
~/.fzf/install
```

Re-source your `~/.bashrc`: `. ~/.bashrc`

Clone `fzf-fs`: `git clone https://github.com/D630/fzf-fs ~/fzf-fs`

Add `~/fzf-fs` to your `PATH`: `PATH=$PATH:~/fzf-fs`
Run `fzf-fs --init`
Define an alias: `alias vcd='. fzf-fs'`
Run `vcd ~`
You should see something like this:
[image]

Choose directory with <kbd>Enter</kbd>, use fuzzy searching, type `[q]` to exit.

See also: [fzf-fs USAGE](https://github.com/D630/fzf-fs/blob/master/doc/USAGE.md), <del>[fzf-fs doesn't support newlines in filenames](https://github.com/D630/fzf-fs/issues/11)</del> fixed for `cd`!

Comment: That's really nice utility, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

While I do not know a tool that fits your description, perhaps some of the small utilities mentioned below would be helpful?

`pushd` and `popd`, [described here](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/smarter-directory-navigation/) along with other tools that can boost productivity while navigating around

[fasd](https://github.com/clvv/fasd) - offers quick access to files and directories for POSIX shells

[autojump](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump) - a `cd` that learns

[z](https://github.com/rupa/z) - a variation on the above

[v](https://github.com/rupa/v) - `z` for vim

Answer (score 2):

Something like PC Magazine's `DM` from back in the DOS days... I don't know of a similar program on Linux, but I quite like [`xd`](http://xd-home.sourceforge.net/) for navigating around directories; with a function defined as

```
xd() {
    cd "$(/usr/bin/xd "$@")"
}
```

you can type for example

```
xd /ulb
```

which will print a list of all directories matching `/u*/l*/b*` (`/usr/lib/binfmt.d`, `/usr/local/bin`...), ask you to pick one and change to it.

Comment: hm, `xd V3.22.09` doesn't understand my locale settings and doesn't support UTF-8. So, `xd ф` prints `no solutions` for `ф` but `xd $'\xd1'` prints `1: /home/.../ф`

Comment: Would you mind filing a bug (`reportbug xd`)? The Debian maintainer is `xd`'s author so you'll be talking directly to the right person :-).

Comment: thanks for the reminder. I should check the latest version of `xd` before sending a bug report:)

Answer (score 2):

Try this third party tool: **CDI - Change directory interactive**

Repo: https://github.com/antonioolf/cdi

With this open source tool, just type the command `cdi` in the terminal to open the folder structure and it will allow you to browse the directories using the arrow keys (Right/Left to  Enter/leave a folder).

When you press enter the conventional `CD` command will be executed internally passing the folder chosen as a parameter.

**Installation**

Copy paste and run in your terminal

```
curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antonioolf/cdi/master/install.sh | bash
```

More info: https://github.com/antonioolf/cdi

Author: Antônio Oliveira (Me)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [nnn](https://github.com/jarun/nnn) file manager to interactively browse and select a directory.

And you can configure it to change into the selected directory on exit (when pressing Ctrl+G or always).

> Pick the appropriate file for your shell from misc/quitcd and add the contents to your shell's rc file. You'll need to spawn a new shell for the change to take effect. You should start nnn as n (or your preferred function name/alias).
>
> By default, when ^G is pressed, nnn writes the last working directory
> to
>
> ${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/nnn/.lastd
>
> To cd on quit always, export the environment variable NNN_TMPFILE set
> to your preferred file path.
>
> The extra key ^G to cd on quit is to avoid writing to a file every
> time nnn quits and allows on-demand cd on quit

[1](https://github.com/jarun/nnn/wiki/Basic-use-cases#configure-cd-on-quit=)

Answer (score 0):

ZSH shell provides an interactive `cd`. ZSH is an extension of the Linux shell.

ZSH shell will display all candidates if you hit the `tab` during `cd` and allow you to select the right candidate with `tab`.

---

Notice that the 'tab' autocompletion in ZHS behaves differently than the default 'tab' autocompletion in native Linux shells.

While both will do the autocompletion neatly when only one candidate exists.

When multiple candidates exist, the behaviour of ZSH and native shells is different.

The native shells will list all the candidates directly in the output and exit the `cd` command. So you have to reenter the command. (but actually, you have to hit twice the `tab` key to see this reaction. You will get no output when you hit only once the `tab` key)

The ZSH, however, will list all candidates as hints (without exit `cd` command) and allow you to select the preferred one with `tab` or arrow keys `↑` `↓` `→` `←`. After the candidate is selected, you are allowed to continue to type the reset of your command on the same line.

Below is a screenshot, you can see the folder 'Downloads' is selected and therefore automatically completed on the command line. And you are still allowed to finish your command.
[image]

For installation, you can check the ZSH [installation instructions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-z-shellzsh-on-linux/)

Comment: Welcome to the site. It would seem that you are describing [tab completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion#Completion_in_different_command_line_interfaces) which most shells implement nowadays, not just `zsh`. If that was not intended, please consider editing your post to make the distinctive feature of `zsh` you are describing more prominent.