# sh: is there a command to interactively edit the PWD?

Tags: shell, zsh, cd-command, pwd, interactive

I'm looking for a command that invokes `readline` or similar, primed with the current `$PWD`, to let the user edit the current directory, then `cd` to the edited value. E.g.

```
> cd ~/a/b/c/d
> pwd
> /home/alice/a/b/c/d
```

Then run the proposed `icd` command (for "interactive `cd`", inspired by 
`imv` in [renameutils](https://www.nongnu.org/renameutils/)). It prompts the user as follows:

```
> icd
icd> /home/alice/a/b/c/d
```

Then the user can, e.g. press Alt-b, Alt-b, Alt-t, resulting in:

```
icd> /home/alice/a/c/b/d
```

(Alt-t transposing `b` and `c`)

Upon pressing Enter, the `icd` command changes the current directory to `/home/alice/a/c/b/d`.

Ideally `icd` would have some autocompletion. Maybe even visual indication of whether the current value is an existing/valid directory.

This can nearly be done in zsh by typing

```
> cd `pwd`
```

then pressing Tab. But a command like `icd` would save keystrokes.

Related: [Interactive cd (directory browser)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212058/interactive-cd-directory-browser)

Comment: Your title says "sh"; did you mean for something POSIX-compliant, or zsh-focused?

Comment: zsh-focused would be fine, since I use it, but I put "sh" because I figured this would be easy enough to do-able in basic `sh`, making the answer more generally helpful, while also still probably compatible with `zsh`. I named a shell at all because, e.g. a `csh`-specific answer would not help me.

Comment: An sh like like dash has so few line-editing features that I'd imagine something like this would be hundreds of times more difficult there. (Not that anyone uses dash interactively, I hope)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `bash` and any other shell supporting `readline` you might be able to use this function

```
icd() { local a; read -ei "${1:-$PWD}" -p "$FUNCNAME> " a && cd "$a"; }
```

Usage

```
icd          # Starts editing with $PWD
icd /root    # Starts editing with /root
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! Unfortunately `zsh`'s `read` doesn't support `-i`. But modifying your solution to use `vared` works for me: `icd() { local a="${1:-$PWD}"; vared -p "$FUNCNAME> " a && cd "$a"; }`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done at least in zsh. A similar thing is [built into fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/key-bindings.zsh), where you can press <kbd>Alt+C</kbd> to cd into a directory through fuzzy selection:

Instead of fzf, one could presumably use your proposed `icd` tool.

I do not believe it can be done in a POSIX-compliant way.